# Kerberos , how to fix "KDC cannot accommodate requested option."

Tags: alfresco, kerberos

I am trying to configure alfresco 5.0d community to use kerberos and SSO via active directory.
My setup works fine when I login in the alfresco form login page (without SSO),

However, When enabling SSO, I see this exception in the alfresco logfile:

```
KrbException: KDC cannot accommodate requested option (13)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsRep.<init>(KrbTgsRep.java:70)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.getReply(KrbTgsReq.java:259)
```

After looking at it with wireshark, it seems like the difference in the TGS-REQ message is that **when using SSO**, there is an option flag called **request-anonymous** that is enabled. This causes the KDC to answer with a KDC_ERR_BADOPTION message.

Is there a way to configure kerberos to not set the request-anonymous flag? 
Or alternitavely, is there a way to tell the KDC server to deal with it properly?

Comment: What options did you specify when you created the kerberos keytab on the Alfresco machine?

Comment: I used the command presented in the guide at http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/auth-kerberos-ADconfig.html. my domain is COMP.local and host alfresco-test, so my command looks like this : ktpass -princ HTTP/alfresco-test.COMP.local@COMP.LOCAL -pass xxx -mapuser 
COMP\httpalfresco-test -crypto all -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -out c:\temp\http<alfresco-test.keytab -kvno 0

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  Is the environment still available to test with by any chance?

Comment: No, never got it resolved. The environment was on an internal network.